# Call one Ruby Script from Another

Tags: ruby, paypal

I am having a perplexing problem.  I want to call one ruby script from another.

With this in mind, I create a testscript.rb and executed it, it contains this code,

```
 require './paypal.rb'
 puts paypal['L_AMT0']
```

This code returns a number, which is my paypal balance.  It relies on a paypal.rb file which uses the ruby-paypal gem.  When I do ruby testscript.rb I get the output of my paypal balance, which means it is working properly.  This tells me that my method for calling one RB from another is okay, since, in the above scenario, testscript.rb is getting a variable that is returned from paypal.rb.

Using this same logic, I inserted the above code into another program which is called SiriProxy.  It is a ruby program.  I need it to get my paypal balance.

So Inside that program, I did a require paypal.rb, it failed because it could not find it, so I set an absolute path in require which fixed it.

However, when SiriProxy (the other ruby rb giving me an issue) trys to run puts paypal['L_AMT0'] it results in an error and ends the program.

This is the error,

```
[Info - Plugin Manager] Say: Checking Paypal Balance
/home/siriproxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@SiriProxy/gems/siriproxy-0.3.0/plugins/siriproxy-example/lib/siriproxy-example.rb:47:in `block in <class:Example>': undefined local variable or method `paypal' for #<SiriProxy::Plugin::Example:0x931a228> (NameError)
    from /home/siriproxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@SiriProxy/bundler/gems/cora-1edcfb9073d5/lib/cora/plugin.rb:47:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/siriproxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@SiriProxy/bundler/gems/cora-1edcfb9073d5/lib/cora/plugin.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in process'
```

In the above output it appears the issue is it does not understand "paypal", as seen here:

> undefined local variable or method `paypal'

However, I do not understand why, since in testscript.rb I do the exact same thing and it works.

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Loading Files from the Current Directory

I don't know anything about your library or its internals, but it looks like your require statement may be wrong. If you want to load a file from the current directory in Ruby 1.9.3, you should use:

```
require_relative 'paypal'
```

#### Bundler and Gems

If it's a gem that you've installed as part of a bundle (e.g. the gem is defined in a Gemfile), then providing a path in your require statement is wrong. Instead, you need to require the bundled gem as follows:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'paypal'
```

Comment: When I try that it throws an error, /home/siriproxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@SiriProxy/gems/siriproxy-0.3.0/plugins/siriproxy-example/lib/siriproxy-example.rb:3:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /home/siriproxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@SiriProxy/gems/siriproxy-0.3.0/plugins/siriproxy-example/lib/paypal (LoadError)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like @CodeGnome is right.

[From the Kernel documentation:](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require)

**require(name) → true or false**

> Loads the given name, returning true if successful and false if the
>   feature is already loaded.

**require_relative(string) → true or false**

> Ruby tries to load the library named string relative to the requiring
>   file’s path. If the file’s path cannot be determined a LoadError is
>   raised. If a file is loaded true is returned and false otherwise.

Comment: I agree, but when I do that I get an error,

/home/siriproxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@SiriProxy/gems/siriproxy-0.3.0/plugins/siriproxy-example/lib/siriproxy-example.rb:3:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /home/siriproxy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@SiriProxy/gems/siriproxy-0.3.0/plugins/siriproxy-example/lib/paypal (LoadError)